# Randomly modify a 3D vector

Tags: 3d, geometry

Given a vector, is there a simple way of disturbing it by an adjustable random amount, to point it in a slightly different direction? E.g randomly adjust it by 0.1 radians, or all the up to 2pi radians. Randomly adjusting the components doesn't really work.

My plan is to generate a random vector, cross product that with my original vector, and then rotate the original vector a random amount around that. Is that a decent idea?

Clearer description: imagine there's a cone with apex at the origin, pointing in the same direction as the vector, with a configurable opening angle - i want to be able to choose a random vector that points from the origin to any angle within that cone

Comment: "randomly adjust it by 0.1 radians" - in what direction, or is this referring to the pitch / yaw? If you mean shifting it by some angular distance in a random direction, then your method should work just fine.

Comment: imagine there's a cone with apex at the origin, pointing in the same direction as the vector, with a configurable opening angle - i want to be able to choose a random vector that points from the origin to any angle within that cone

Comment: Then your approach should work fine, provided that you perform the relevant checks. However it does not generate a uniform distribution over the cone's base area.

Comment: its fine if the distribution over the base is not uniform, only that the angular distribution is. What relevant checks do I need? Just that the random 'reference' vector isn't parallel with the original vector?

Comment: Yes (+anti-parallel) and ideally it shouldn't be "too close" (dot product within some small range of +1 / -1) either for the sake of numerical stability.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method to generate perpendicular vector explicitly.

Find components with the largest and the second magnitudes.

Exchange these components and negate the largest. Make the smallest component zero. For example, if for vector `V   |y|>=|x|>=|z|`, then vector `P=(-y, x, 0)` is perpendicular (check dot product).

To make arbitrary perpendicular, generate also `B = V x P`, normalize `P` and `B` and make combination

```
 R = L * P * Cos(t) + L * B * Sin(t)
```

where `t` is random angle in range `0..2*Pi`, and `L` is length to provide deviation angle `tan(fi) = L / |V|`

Now deviated vector is (with length equal to source one).

```
D = (V + R) * |V|/|V+R|
```

Distribution is not uniform if `fi` is uniform in cone angle range. Seems the transformation below should provide uniform distribution:

```
 L = V * tan(Sqrt(random(0..1))*FiCone)
```

Comment: This is only sufficiently uniform in the small-angle limit; for larger angles one must use `sqrt(sin(angle/2))` in place of the canonical "`sqrt(r)`".

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Now I suspect that descibed approach is too complex for author' s purposes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution that appears to work, confirmed ok by **@meowgoesthedog** - I generate a random unit vector that's not parallel with the original vector, cross product them together to get a random axis of rotation, and then rotate the original vector around that by a random amount.

I've implemented it and it seems to work perfectly.